# Hiding url extension for module name

Tags: url, hide, visible

I was hoping somebody would be able to help me,

I am looking for a way to hide my extension in my urls. for example :

http://website/index.php?route=thispart/designer&path=&product_id=1202

I would like to hide or change my url fully or partially in any way providing that the "thispart" is hidden from public viewing. "thispart" actually refers to a module installed within my opencart platform.

Would really appreciate your help

Thank you in advance.

Soyeb